# ContentSize Height of UIScrollView in iPhone X not updating

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swift4, iphone-x

This issue sounds easy at first but this is one of those things that I had to ask a question for suggestions since there is no other way I can think of to solve this. I already searched too far for solutions but did not find any.

#### Situation

I have a collection view that scrolls horizontally that covers the whole screen.

I added a scroll view inside each cell's content view that contains several views that will be taller than screen height.

After the last subview is added I update scroll view content size using:

`scrollview.contentSize = CGSize.init(width: screenWidth, height: (scrollview.subviews.last?.frame.origin.y)! + (scrollview.subviews.last?.frame.size.height)!)`

Let's say "scrollview" is the scroll view and "screenWidth" is the width of the screen. It works on other devices except iPhone X will scroll maybe for two screen heights worth but that's it. Other devices can go to the bottom of the scroll view.

While writing this I thought:

*what if I need to add top and bottom padding of safe area to content size height since it extends there.*

I did it but it only added so little and a big part of views still cannot be seen due to this issue.

Inputs are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: scrollviews are tricky. Whenever I've had these type of scenarios, I just add **all** my views inside a stackView and the the stack view has top/bottom/leading/trailing constraints to scrollView (stackView is inside scrollView). It's also important to set that stackView has same width as scrollView. Then you don't need to manually modify the scrollView contentSize. It works alone with the stackView inside.